# Select constant along with * in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake, say like:

`MyTable`

```
A   |  B 
---------
12. |. 12 
13. |. 13
```

I want to do something like `SELECT "myconstant" as newcolumn, MyTable.* from MyTable"` so the result is like:

```
newcolumn | A   |  B 
--------------------
myconstant| 12. |. 12 
myconstant| 13. |. 13
```

But I get the error saying

```
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 invalid identifier 'myconstant'
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String constants aka literals](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#string-constants) are wrapped with `'` or `$$`:

```
SELECT 'myconstant' as newcolumn, MyTable.* from MyTable;

SELECT $$myconstant$$ as newcolumn, MyTable.* from MyTable;
```

Comment: which also means, double quotes are only for table and columns names.